# Single User Mode can´t repair my HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are next steps when fsck reports “could not be repaired after 3 attempts”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81093/what-are-next-steps-when-fsck-reports-could-not-be-repaired-after-3-attempts)

Hi Guys I hope someone can save me!!!

I´m so stupid that I don´t have a backup of my files and I have 220 GB of Photos, Music and Work in one Partition. Now it won´t start.

Now that I have an external HD I´m desperate to find a way to save my files but I don´t know how to do it in Disk utilities or Route Shell. I have read there is a DiskWarrior but I have no clue how to install it without entering my Macintosh HD.

When I run fsck_hfs in Single User Mode this is what I see, hopefully someone can help me thank you from the heart:

```
Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557-393)
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
The volume name is Macintosh HD
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file
Incorrect number of thread records 
(4, 23745)
Checking multi-linked files.
Checking catalog hierarchy
Invalid volume directory count
(It should be 175703 instead of 175701)
Checking extended attributes file.
Incorrect number of extended attributes
(It should be 340062 instead of 340064)
Checking volume bitmap.
Checking volume information.
The volume Macintosh HD could not be repaired after 3 attempts
```

Comment: Let's close this for now - it's so close to the other question, it might be better to add the comment here that you do not have a back up to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81093/

Comment: Also, for this to really be answered, you'll want to review the guide on [ask] and list some specific error messages or detail what you tried to get DW to work. Saying you don't know what to do is a good first step and people will explain RTFM (with F being friendly) but you'll want to document a bit of what you did to try to solve the DW won't install / run for someone to not have to guess what issue you are facing. We prefer "detailed questions that stand alone" as opposed to "general - help me until I solve X with many iterations of details along the way" type questions.

Answer (score 0):

DiskWarrior ships with a recovery CD/DVD and has instructions/phone/web support on how to deploy it once you have purchased it. Since it's commercial software, they provide support in getting it installed and working.

Similarly, you could boot into Recovery HD and work on fixing or erasing the drive as the situation warrants.